# Stop a method from repeating when activity is closed

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
    final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query mSeenRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).orderByChild("From").equalTo(MessageRecieverId);
    mSeenRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String keyId = ds.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference mSendersRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child(keyId);
                    DatabaseReference mRecieversRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageRecieverId).child(MessageSenderId).child(keyId);
                    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                    childUpdates.put("Seen", true);
                    mSendersRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
                    mRecieversRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

This code is just to set `SEEN=true` on a basic chat app and it works fine when u open the activity.

If user A opens the chat activity B gets notified that messages are seen and when the user A is in the chat B still continuously gets notified that A is seeing Bs messages but once A exits the chat the messages B send are still termed as Seen by A even though A isn't inside the activity.

Only when A closes the app(even from the background) B stops getting his messages to A as seen by A.

I'm sure the problem is because of this method so I just want to know how to make this method stop executing after the activity is closed. This method is in the onCreate of `ChatActivity`.

Comment: the method will trigger everytime a new message comes since addValueEventListener is listening all the time at your reference for new values, to fix it you can use addListenerForSingleValue but that will trigger only once

Comment: Thanks a ton mate @GastónSaillén

Comment: added it to the answer so others can find the answer helpfull too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method will trigger everytime a new message comes since `addValueEventListener` is listening all the time at your reference for changes, to fix it you can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` but that will trigger only once.

From the docs

### Read data once

> In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then
>   immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you
>   don't expect to change. You can use the
>   addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to simplify this scenario: it
>   triggers once and then does not trigger again.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the hint ! Voted up :)